# What is this equation, written on a wall?

Tags: laplace-transform

I was asked to ID the following, but can't figure out what it's for. Laplace Transform of acceleration (*x double-dot*)?

[image: Original EQ]

*(Sorry that I can't provide a sharper image - this is all I have access to)*

I don't recognize the infinite sum, and there are some squiggles around the `r` in the denominator that I can't quite make out.

I tried to transcribe it, but since I'm not entirely sure what's going on in the denominator, I can't be certain it's accurate.

[image: Transcribed]

It seems odd to me to see a negative exponent in the denominator, and it's confusing using `i` as a counting variable.

Thanks in advance.

**Context**

There is none. This was sent to me by a friend, off of a "what is this" site. No known artist, location, date, etc.

**Edit #1 - Additional Posting**

Also posted in [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/343346/what-is-this-equation-written-on-a-wall?noredirect=1#comment769559_343346), maybe something going on over there will spark a thought. Not much more (or any) insight beyond what's in this thread though.

**Edit #2 - Re-done Equation with "knowns"**

Based on some comments, and things not previously seen/added to original transcribed equation, I've got the following:

[image: Re-done]

The changes aren't substantial. The coefficient for the `r'` in the denominator has been proposed as being `n`, or `2`. Additionally, having stared at this a bit longer, the two `2` exponents could also be sloppily-written thetas. Probably not.

All-in-all, it seems that this is most likely trolling.

Comment: Maybe, it means the square of $(x-ir')^-$, where $x^-=(x-|x|)/2$? But no, this would give 0 in denominator...

Comment: (1) There is a closed contour double integral with limits from infinity to phi in the original image. (2) But the integrand only has dx rather than a 2-form (3) What sort of maniac puts negative powers in the denominator? At this point the decoration on that input x seems about as meaningful as the umlaut over blue oyster cult's logo

Comment: @ViditNanda maybe the negative exponent isn't supposed to be negative? Perhaps they forgot to make the exponent positive, when bringing the group down?

Comment: It seems only Jaime, Kenneth, and Neddy know what it means.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar : Looks like "Janine" rather than "Jaime" to me. But I agree with Vidit that it looks like gibberish (though the acceleration symbol is one of the least nonsensical parts in my opinion). Note also that there seems to be an $n$ between the integral and the sum.

Comment: @TimothyChow it would appear to be so. Didn't notice it until just now. BUT THEN WHAT'S `n`!? Maybe the sum is `n=-infinity..infinity`, but for some reason they throw an odd-looking `i` in there for kicks? The `i` in the denominator is missing its characteristic dot, so perhaps the stucco - in concert with the angle of the photo - is squishing an 'n' and making `nr'` look like `ir'`?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/356/

Comment: Not just an n; there seem to be Greek letter "limits" on what would normally be a surface integral.  The only way I could begin parsing this is by assuming x stands for a complex variable, and that it is not a contour integral but something over a domain that includes an open set of complex numbers, perhaps an annulus?  What wall is this on? Gerhard "Then Again, It's Probably Trolling" Paseman, 2017.07.06.

Comment: What is being interpreted as $i r '$ in the denominator, looks to me as possibly $2 r '$ instead (tiny $2$). And it might not be $r$.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke if that's the case, then the summation is moot, since the counter variable (`i`? `n`?) never appears within. It seems that this gem was written by a) an idiot or somebody mistaken, b) a genius with intellect far beyond that of the entire internet or c) a world-class troll. Hmmm.

Comment: If there were not one too many brackets, the "$r'$" could actually be "$)^{-1}$".

Comment: Regarding Willie's post, is that a truck I hear?  Gerhard "Thinks He'll Be Moving Along" Paseman, 2017.07.06.

Comment: If this is a real question, you should at least provide some more details -- i.e. where and when was this written on the wall, how and by whom have you been asked "to ID" this, and what else do you know about the context? -- As it stands, this question looks to me pretty much like trolling.

Comment: @StefanKohl it was sent to me by a friend, because of my mathematics/physics background. There is no context. The photo came from a "what is this" website. No location, no author, no nothing. I'm as curious about this as anybody else, and sincerely disappointed that it's turning out to be nothing more than a wild goose chase.

Comment: @StefanKohl ---   https://www.reddit.com/r/whatisthisthing/comments/6lmcge/what_is_this_formula_it_was_written_on_the_wall/

Comment: and the location is given as "Aungier Street in Dublin, across the road from the Dublin Institute of Technology."

Answer (score 4):

Mene Mene Tekel Upharsin

..................................

[Context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belshazzar's_feast)

Comment: Quite a deep response. Perhaps MathOverflow's day's are numbered.

Comment: Indeed. I expect a major change within less than a million days. Gerhard "I Don't Mean Global Warming" Paseman, 2017.07.06.

Comment: The words of the prophets are written on the subway walls, and tenement halls.